# Getting "" value in $content while parsing URL using curl

Tags: php

Here is my code:

```
$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

$content = curl_exec($ch);

var_dump ($content);
```

I am getting string (0) as I am echoing the value of `$content`. Can anybody tell me why this is happening.

Comment: Add this line to the end of that code block and post back with the output:
`echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);`

Comment: I am already doing this

Comment: You already tried `curl_error()`? I don't see it in the code above... Can you tell us what the output was? Also, what's the value of `$url`?

Comment: any url of any website

Comment: Unfortunately that's really vague and it's going to be hard to help you without more details. Maybe try `http://google.com` as the value of `$url`. Also, make sure PHP error reporting is enabled. Add these 2 lines to the beginning of the code: `ini_set('display_errors', true); ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);`

Comment: Check if you have the cURL extension enabled in your php.ini

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to set url in this way.
I found it in PHP.net:

```
// create curl resource 
$ch = curl_init();
// set url 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "example.com");
```

I hope this help you!